# How to create an approval post in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to approve "posts" before going online,

**the first question is** do I need to code on the **backend**, or I can do it only in the **front-end** in order to add the functionality?

so I have some code that creates a post, and I need to send data to the confirmation page before going to the main page.

here is the code for post creation:

```
      const onSubmit = (data) => {
    if (data.postText) {
      const formData = postToFormData(data, file, createTags);
      axios
        .post(`/posts`, formData, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            accessToken: localStorage.getItem("accessToken"),
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            history.push("/approving");
          }, 2000);
        });
      setMessage("posct created successfully!");
    }
  };
```

so as you see in the code above, we have a post method to post the data, and I need to send the data to the approving page where I need to see all the data and press "approve" or "reject"

## i have 3 states in the main page to display the data:

```
 @{value.fullName}
  {value.postTitle}
  {value.postText}
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You can show another component in the render code without navigate to another page.

Comment: Could you please make it a bit clear, so I can create it, and thanks a lot for the time?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need to modify the backend. Only send a PUT request to update the post (if the backend accept this).

Regarding the other question, you don't need to redirect to another url to show new content in react. You can show different content depending in the state.

```js
const Form = ({submitting, handleSubmit, formData, setFormData}) => {
  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input 
      type="text" 
      required
      value={formData.text} 
      onChange={(e) => setFormData({text: e.target.value})}
    />
    <br />
    <button type="submit">{submitting ? 'Sending...' : 'Save'}</button>
  </form>
}

const Revision = ({formData}) => {
  return <div>
    <p>Your sucess message...</p>
    <p>{formData.text }</p>
    <button>Approve</button>
    <button>Reject</button>
  </div>
}

const App = () => {
  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = React.useState(false)
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = React.useState(false)
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({text: ''})
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setSubmitting(true)
    // Fake send post data
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSubmitted(true)
    }, 1000)
  }
  
  const handleApprove = () => {
    // Send PUT request to update your post.
  }
  
  const handleReject = () => {
    // Send PUT request to update your post.
  }
  
  if (submitted) {
    return <Revision
      formData={formData}
      handleApprove={handleApprove}
      handleReject={handleReject}
    />
  } else {
    return <Form 
      submitting={submitting}
      handleSubmit={handleSubmit} 
      formData={formData}
      setFormData={setFormData}
    />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, i will try it out:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you means by "approve post before going online". But here the scenarios which I think I understood:-

a) **CONFIRMATION FEATURE** before submitting new post to backend (basically create a new set of data in the database) javascript

b) **APPROVE or REJECT FEATURES** after new post successfully submitted & created in the database

For **SCENARIO A**:-

- you may create a component (like a popup or something) that shows user to choose whether they want to **Confirm** or **Cancel** creation of new post data.
- **Confirm** - will triggered the `onSubmit` function and send the data to the backend to create a new post
- **Cancel** - will reset every states to it's default value/state (basically emptying out every input placeholders)

For **SCENARIO B**:-

- you must have some kind of variables in the database that can distinguish which post is approved & which is not. (like `status` or `publish_status` - can be set to either Yes or No or 1 or 0)
- create a new `function` to handle just changing/update of `status/publish_status` var/value in the database of said/selected post. This can be done right after creation of new post (like what you want) or just at anytime you want (basically you have a working UI that handles a list of posts with just the `id`, `title`, `status/publish_status` & `action buttons`  like `edit`, `delete` and/or `publish`, **typically we display this in table** - so if you hit `action button publish`, then it will triggered the `update/put` req to change/update the `status/publish_status` in the database. Just make sure to change your `publish action button text` to `unpublish` if the `put` req successful)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, for the answer, by approving a post before going online, I meant if a user wants to submit a post, so I need to check it before sending it to the database and creating the post, this is just for keeping users safe and secure.